# How to loop through Excel documents in Python?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, loops

I have downloaded a module called **openpyxl** which I intend to use to extract data (parts numbers) out from our many Excel files and then write them into a single file. I have not used Python much and am wondering how I could alter the the following code so that the script would open a spreadsheet, run some code on that spreadsheet, and then move onto the next one. If it was a list or a string of some sort I could write for loops for it but for actual spreadsheets I don't know how this would be done.

Can anyone offer any advice on how to loop through documents like this?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> wb2 = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
>>> print wb2.get_sheet_names()
['Sheet2', 'New Title', 'Sheet1']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get a `list` of the spreadsheets with `os.listdir()` and then extract the data using a `for` loop, like so:

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = "path/to/folder"  # The folder containing the spreadsheets
sheets = os.listdir(path)

for sheet in sheets:
    wb2 = load_workbook(os.path.join(path, sheet))
    print(wb2.get_sheet_names())
    wb2._archive.close()
```